# SQL Server extract value from a strings that represents a map

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a column in a SQL Server table which its SQL is string. The values of this column are actually maps, meaning the format is `(a=1,b=2,c=3)`.

I need to write a SQL query that will return the corresponding value to a given key. For example, for key "b" I need that SQL query to return "2".

Basically I am looking for some regex support with group matching (i.e. something like "b=(\w+),")

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using a data type that actually supports multiple values - such as XML or another table? T-SQL's string processing facilities aren't the best around.

Comment: Because I don't control the DB scheme, i can just use it without changing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Regex in SQL Server without using the [CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/w2kae45k%28v=vs.90%29). That would be a decent option if it is possible in your environment.

Without the CLR you'd be down to using [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Something like this will work but it's not at all pretty or efficient:

```
declare @input varchar(50) = '(a=1,b=2,c=3)'
select
substring(@input, patindex('%a=%', @input) + 2, 
             patindex('%,%', substring(@input, patindex('%a=%', @input) + 2, len(@input))) - 1),
substring(@input, patindex('%b=%', @input) + 2, 
             patindex('%,%', substring(@input, patindex('%b=%', @input) + 2, len(@input))) - 1),
substring(@input, patindex('%c=%', @input) + 2, 
             patindex('%)%', substring(@input, patindex('%c=%', @input) + 2, len(@input))) - 1)
```

Basically this looks for the string `a=` and grabs the index. It then substrings from that index plus 2 (to remove the a=) to the index of the first comma after the `a=`.

This returns 1 2 3 as you'd expect.